# Temporally prevent Panel from updating layout

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, user-interface, panel

Can I set [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) to temporally not to update its layout ? I want to programatically update all its children. Every change might change the layout all children in `Panel` completely. So if it tries to update its layout, the children or its container after every change I do the screen might "freeze".

So I want to prevent the `Panel` from updating layout until I'm finished with its children. I also don't want it to propagate any layout update to its container or children (that I'll be working with).

How can I do that ?

*Note: This question is meant to solve problem described in my question [Auto-sizing elements based on layout position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834187/auto-sizing-elements-based-on-layout-position).*

Comment: You say "might" a lot. Have you actually tried it? As long as you're performing all the changes within the same message, a layout pass will not occur.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: I'll try it soon - I need some test data that will be large enough (so I need to create program that will generate them...) Can you explain what you meant by "within the same message" ?

Comment: I think he's referring to the Windows message pump that the UI thread drives. The Arrange pass won't occur while you're processing the children because it's on the same thread / message loop.